# SQL Case when something AND something THEN

Tags: sql, case

Is possible to have an and statement in a SQL CASE clause? If so how do you write it?

i.e something like this?:

```
CASE
    When ((Column < 1) AND (Column2 > 0)) THEN column4 + 1
END as Column
```

my code that executes but doesn't accomplish what i want (have no negative numbers):

```
CASE
WHEN (((Clean_Total_Time - ActivityTimeTotalMin) < 0) AND (ActivityTimeTotalMin > 0))     
THEN (ABS(DATEDIFF(hh,Total_Time,ActivityTotalTime))-1)
END as hours
```

my code that does work and does accomplish what it should but I don't want it because it allows for negative numbers:

```
CASE
WHEN (Clean_Total_Time - ActivityTimeTotalMin) < 0
THEN (ABS(DATEDIFF(hh,Total_Time,ActivityTotalTime))-1)
END as hours
```

EDIT: The purpose of this calculation is as follows:

It subtracts two columns, and if the result is negative, is subtracts the number one from one of those two columns. Further, my AND section was to say that if that column had a value of zero, then it would not subtract 1 from the column. I don't want that column to have numbers below zero.

The only thing that is not happening, is that it is not catching if the column is equal to zero. So I am getting negative 1 whenever there was originally a 0.

Comment: What you have should work.  Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I tried it, and no error appeared, It just didn't change anything. I'll post my code.

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  It's likely that your `CASE` statement may be leaving out some records and returning `NULL`.

Comment: It subtracts two columns, and if the result is negative, is subtracts the number one from one of those two columns. Further, my AND section was to say that if that column had a value of zero, then it would not subtract 1 from the column. I don't want that column to have numbers below zero.

Comment: wrap the whole thing in an ABS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) it is:

> ```
> SELECT ProductNumber, Name, "Price Range" = 
>       CASE 
>          ...
>          WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'
>          WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'
>          ELSE 'Over $1000'
>       END
> FROM Production.Product
> ```

I just don't think you need the parentheses.

**Update 1**

You can try using `CASE` inside `CASE` like so:

```
CASE
    WHEN Column < 1
        CASE
            WHEN Column2 > 0 THEN column4 + 1
        END
END AS Column
```

Comment: thanks, just tried this, it still would subtract the column if was zero. any other suggestions?